# firebase transaction on lower node - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

after several Q&A about the transaction mechanism I'm trying to run a transaction on a lowel node

here is my data:

```
activeOffers
    -LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p
        details
            direction: "city"
            seatsCount: 2
            timeToGo: 5
        uid: "-ABSIFJ0vCnt9p8387a"    ---- offering user
```

I'm trying to run the transaction on **-LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p** and do the following:

1. decrease the seatsCount by some requested value **if there is enought seats**
2. add a subnode deal under ** -LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p** with the requested value and the uid of the requesting user.

But obviously I don't do it correctly because I get **Maximum call stack size exceeded** even only for step 1.

Here is my code:

(**entryRef** is the ref to **-LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p**)

```
dealSeats = function(entryRef, data) {
    const TAG = '[dealSeats]: ';
    return entryRef.transaction((current)=>{
        if (current) {
            if (current.details.seatsCount >= data.details.seatsCount) {
                current.details.seatsCount -= data.details.seatsCount;
            }
        }
        return current;
    });
}
```

**================ update after Frank van Puffelen's comment ===============**

I don't see any recursion in my flow:

I call the cloud function in Postman sending the following data:

```
{
 "data": 
  {
     "uid": "-FGKKSDFGK12387sddd",    ---- the requesting/asking user
     "id": "-LKpCACQlL25XTWJ0OV_",
     "details":
     {
          "direction": "city",
          "seatsCount": 1,
          "timeToGo": 5
     }
  }
}
```

**===== index.js =====**

```
entries = require('./entries');

/// cloud function
exports.TEST_askOfferSeats = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    return entries.askSeats(data);
});
```

**===== entries.js =======**

```
exports.askSeats = function(data) {
    const TAG = '[askSeats]: ';

    var entryRef = db.ref('activeOffers/' + data.id);
    return globals.exists(entryRef)
        .then((found)=>{
            if (found) {
                return dealSeats(entryRef, data);
            } else {
                return 'Offer not found [' + data.id + ']';
            }
        });
}
```

and here is the stacktrace in the error log:

```
function:
  TEST_askOfferSeats
event message:
  Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
      at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13395:23)
      at encode (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/lib/providers/https.js:204:18)
      at /user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:38
      at /user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15
      at baseForOwn (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3010:24)
      at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13399:7)
      at encode (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/lib/providers/https.js:204:18)
      at /user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:38
      at /user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15
      at baseForOwn (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3010:24)
      at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-         
  functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13399:7)
```

I don't have any triggers or something that could call again and again the same code...

Comment: The code you shared does not have any recursion in it, so it seems unlikely that it'll cause that problem. Can you update the question with: 1)  the complete stack trace, 2) how you're invoking `dealSeats`?

Comment: thanks, I've updated the post with real flow and data and the stacktrace. The flow is really simple and there is no recursion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally it appeared to be very very stupid of me.
If I wanted to use transaction returning a promise I should put

```
  .then((success)=>{   ...   }
```

after the transaction.  i.e.:

```
 return entryRef.transaction((current)=>{
    if (current) {
        if (current.details.seatsCount >= data.details.seatsCount) {
            current.details.seatsCount -= data.details.seatsCount;
        }
    }
    return current;
})
.then((success)=> {
.......
});
```

And everything is fine now :)