# Firebase: is it good enough to check if reference exists before start a transaction

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I wonder if it is good enough to test if the reference exists
BEFORE  I start a transaction on this reference?
e.g: by using .once('value') and snapshot.exists()

I mean if the check is outside the transaction isn't there a risk another user to delete the reference just after the check and before the transacton executor function?

**==== edited to include the minimal complete code =====**

here is my data in realtime database:

```
activeOffers
    -LKohyZ58cnzn0vCnt9p
        details
            direction: "city"
            seatsCount: 2
            timeToGo: 5
        uid: "-ABSIFJ0vCnt9p8387a"    ---- offering user
```

And here is my code flow:

**===== index.js =====**

```
entries = require('./entries');

/// cloud function
exports.TEST_askOfferSeats = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    return entries.askSeats(data);
});
```

here is my test data sent by Postman:

```
{
 "data": 
  {
     "uid": "-FGKKSDFGK12387sddd",    ---- the requesting/asking user
     "id": "-LKpCACQlL25XTWJ0OV_",
     "details":
     {
          "direction": "city",
          "seatsCount": 1,
          "timeToGo": 5
     }
  }
}
```

**===== entries.js =======**

```
exports.askSeats = function(data) {
const TAG = '[askSeats]: ';

var entryRef = db.ref('activeOffers/' + data.id);
return globals.exists(entryRef)
    .then((found)=>{
        if (found) {
            return dealSeats(entryRef, data);
        } else {
            return 'Offer not found [' + data.id + ']';
        }
    });
}
```

**===== globals.js ======**

```
exports.exists = (ref)=>{
    return ref.once('value')
        .then((snapshot)=>{
            return (snapshot.exists());
        });
}
```

**===== entries.js =====**

```
dealSeats = function(entryRef, data) {
    const TAG = '[dealSeats]: ';
    return entryRef.transaction((entry)=>{
        if (entry) {
            if ((entry.deals) && (entry.deals[data.uid])) {
                throw new Error('You've already made a deal.');
            } else if (entry.details.seatsCount >= data.details.seatsCount) {
                entry.details.seatsCount -= data.details.seatsCount;
                var deal = [];
                deal.status = 'asked';
                deal.details = data.details;
                if (!entry.deals) {
                    entry.deals = {};
                }
                entry.deals[data.uid] = deal;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Not enought seats.');
            }
        }
        return entry;
    })
    .then((success)=>{
        return success.snapshot.val();
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}
```

Btw: is this 'throw new Error(......)' is the correct way to break the transaction ?

**========= updated with final source ===**

Thanks to Doug Stevenson.

So here is my final source that is working fine. If someone sees a potential problem please let me know. Thanks.

```
dealSeats = function(entryRef, data) {
    const TAG = '[dealSeats]: ';
    var abortReason;

    return entryRef.transaction((entry)=>{
        if (entry) {
            if ((entry.deals) && (entry.deals[data.uid])) {
                abortReason = 'You already made a reservation';
                return; // abort transaction
            } else if (entry.details.seatsCount >= data.details.seatsCount) {
                entry.details.seatsCount -= data.details.seatsCount;
                var deal = [];
                deal.status = 'asked';
                deal.details = data.details;
                if (!entry.deals) {
                    entry.deals = {};
                }
                entry.deals[data.uid] = deal;
                // Reservation is made
            } else {
                abortReason = 'Not enought seats';
                return; // abort transaction
            }
        }
        return entry;
     })
    .then((result)=>{ // resolved
        if (!result.committed) { // aborted
            return abortReason;
        } else {
            let value = result.snapshot.val();
            if (value) {
                return value;
            } else {
                return 'Offer does not exists';
            }
        }
    })
     .catch((reason)=>{ // rejected
        return Promise.reject(reason);
    });
}
```

Comment: Given that a transaction will already trigger a read of the value, why would you want to do the read with extra code of your own? This sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me: what are you trying to accomplish with the extra read?

Comment: So do you mean that in my case I've described in another question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043552/firebase-transaction-on-lower-node-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded?noredirect=1#comment91038745_52043552))
I have extra code in exports.askSeats(...) function checking if entryRef exists before I call dealSeats(entryRef,....) function where is my transactio logic?

Is it ok to skip this exists check and go straight to dealSeats(entryRef,.....).
Would the transaction handle it correctly ?

Comment: Please include the minimal, complete code that you're asking about in this question.

Comment: Ok, I've included my code and data related to this flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read a value before a transaction, then read it again inside the transaction, you have absolutely no guarantee that the second read inside the transaction will yield the same result as the initial read outside before the transaction.  It could be modified by the time the transaction is performed.

If you want a truly atomic update, only check value that participate in the transaction within the transaction itself, and make a decision about what to do in the transaction handler.

Comment: Yes. Its clear about the value but what about the existance of the reference itself? Is the null value in transaction (after the first 'null case^ is handled) analogue to not existing refwrence/path

Comment: I don't understand. Reference objects are never null if created by the Firestore SDK.

Comment: I've included 'minimal complete source code'. Would you take a look what I mean please.
I use realtime database. is the same valid for it too?

Comment: If  this 'if (entry)' inside the transaction is enough to check if the offer  with given id exists would be great.

Comment: I don't see what the problem would be.  Does it behave the way you want?

Comment: not exactly.   If the 'offer' does not exists the function finishes with timeout.

Comment: It would be a good idea to update your question with the information about what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.

I've resolved my problem :)
I'll accept you answer.  Now I don't have the extra code for checking if ref exists and I've done it correctly inside the transaction. 
I'll update my post with the final source.